# How much of my javascript jquery code do I need to repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is a softball question and I'm sorry, but how much of my jquery code do I need to repeat in my .js script file? (I'm new to coding and teaching myself!)

Here is what I have, I need to use IDs to open different panels one at a time. But are parts of this redundant?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready
     (function()
         {$("#details-header-1").click
           (function()
              {$("#details-panel-1").slideToggle("slow");}
            );
          }
           );

$(document).ready
         (function()
             {$("#details-header-2").click
               (function()
                  {$("#details-panel-2").slideToggle("slow");}
                );
              }
           );
```

etc...

the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="details-header-1">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="details-panel-1">Hello world!</div>

<div id="details-header-2">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="details-panel-2>Hello world!</div>
```

etc...

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the details-headers and the details-panels (show where they're located in the DOM with relation to each other)?

Comment: Could you post the HTML please?

Comment: You only need one `$(document).ready`. Why not have an html `class` attribute you can loop over with `$('.detailsHeader').each(function(i, e){ var h = $(e); h.click(function(){ h.find('.detailsPannel').slideToggle('slow'); }); });`?

Comment: enumerated *(properties, variables, ...) whatever* are often a sign that you're doing something wrong; that something should be a list. If you show your markup, we could probably get away from the ID's at all and make a generic solution that only uses classes => a single function in JS that handles all occurances.

Comment: Besides that, your formatting is awful  it "hides" the function calls and makes them look like [tag:IIFE]s at the first glance.

Comment: Ok thanks all! I'll post the html in a minute I just need to put it together

Comment: Ok I just updated the original post with html. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#details-header-1").on('click', function() { 
        $("#details-panel-1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#details-header-2").on('click', function() {
        $("#details-panel-2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I’m now guessing this isn’t the “right” way to do it but this is what I was looking for…

Comment: Thanks. I'd say this is "one of the right ways". If this satisfies your needs, please mark as accepted. Or if some other suits better, mark that one.

Answer (score 5):

You can select all IDs that start with `details-header`, and inside the `.click`, select the `details-panel` with the same suffix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $([id^="details-header]").click(function() {
    const num = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $(`.details-panel-${num}`).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

There's probably a *much* more elegant solution, but it's hard to say without seeing the HTML.

Lacking that, you could also give the headers and panels classes instead of multiple different IDs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const headers = $('.details-header');
  const panels = $('.details-panel');
  headers.click(function() {
    const index = headers.index(this);
    $(panels[index]).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have sensibly structured HTML you can use this to your advantage. As you've not given us any I'll provide a generic example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Use on with this syntax so any dynamically added sections
  //also have the event handerl
  $(".details").on("click", ".detailsHeader", function() {
    //Get the detailsSection parent/ancestor
    let parent = $(this).closest(".detailsSection");
    //now toggle the child
    $(parent).find(".detailsBody").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
  <section class="detailsSection">
    <h1 class="detailsHeader">Header 1</h1>
    <div class="detailsBody">Details Body 1
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="detailsSection">
    <h1 class="detailsHeader">Header 2</h1>
    <div class="detailsBody">Details Body 2
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Given the HTML now supplied, you can use jQueries [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".details-header").on("click", function() {
    //Get the next "details-panel"
    var next = $(this).next(".details-panel");
    //Toggle it
    next.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="details-header">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="details-panel">Hello world!</div>

<div class="details-header">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="details-panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you only need to use one document ready function everything inside will wait for the page to load there is no need to include it twice like you are doing.

Secondly, switch from ids to classes if you give all the buttons that need the click handler attached to it the same class then you can declare it just once and it will attach to all elements with that class.

so it can look something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".slideToggle").click( function(event) {

         //you will need to show your html in order for me to helo you dynamically show the corresponding panel
    });

});
```

Depending on how your HTML is structured you will need to use some jquery to find the corresponding panel to show based on the click event.

Comment: Ok thanks all! I'll post the html in a minute I just need to put it together...

Comment: Ok I just updated the original post with html. Sorry for the delay!